# Struct con ámbito global

Tags: c#, struct

estoy intentando entender la interfaz `IEnumerable`, aunque esto no es relevante, lo especifico solo por el sinsentido del código, ya que es solo a modo de prueba.
Lo que intento, es crear una estructura de datos propia `i` poder iterarla con `Foreach`.
Lo hago mediante un Struct i dejando de lado que el return de la classe CDades me devuelve el error (Error CS1503 Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de `System.Collections.Generic.List<IEnumerableProva.CDades.TipData>` a `System.Collections.Generic.List<TipData>` )
veo que tampoco puedo acceder a este struct desde otra classe, pero tampoco puedo definir su ámbito como estático.
¿Alguien me puede echar un cable por favor?

```
namespace IEnumerableProva
{
    class CDades : IEnumerable
    {
         struct TipData
        {
             public int val1;
             public string val2;
        }
        private List<TipData> llista = new List<TipData>();
        public CDades()
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
            {
                llista.Add(new TipData { val1 = n, val2 = $"string " + n });
            }
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new EnumItem(llista);
        }
    }

    class EnumItem : IEnumerator
    {

        private List<TipData> Cllista = new List<TipData>();
        private int pos = -1;
        public EnumItem(List<TipData> pllista)
        {
            Cllista = pllista;

        }
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            pos++;
            if (pos < Cllista.Count && pos % 2 == 0)
                return true;
             else 
                return false;
        }
        public void Reset()
        {
            pos = -1;
        }
        public object Current
        {
            get { return Cllista[pos]; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ese struct es privado (igual que la clase, todo lo que no se aclara es privado)

Answer (score 0):

2 Cosas:

1. Para solucionar los errores que te muestra el compilador debes hacer publico el struct: `TipData` y hacer referencia al mismo con el nombre de la clase que lo contiene en este caso: `CDades` (también puedes hacer una importación estática).

   ```
   class CDades : IEnumerable
   {
       public struct TipData
       {
           public int val1;
           public string val2;
       }
       private List<TipData> llista = new List<TipData>();
       public CDades()
       {
           for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
           {
               llista.Add(new TipData { val1 = n, val2 = $"string " + n });
           }
       }
       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           return new EnumItem(llista);
       }
   }

   class EnumItem : IEnumerator
   {

       private List<CDades.TipData> Cllista = new List<CDades.TipData>();
       private int pos = -1;
       public EnumItem(List<CDades.TipData> pllista)
       {
           Cllista = pllista;

       }
       public bool MoveNext()
       {
           pos++;
           if (pos < Cllista.Count && pos % 2 == 0)
               return true;
           else
               return false;
       }
       public void Reset()
       {
           pos = -1;
       }
       public object Current
       {
           get { return Cllista[pos]; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Probando tu ejemplo puedo ver que tienes `pos % 2 == 0` en el `MoveNext`.
   Una vez este método retorna false es como si el arreglo llegara a su fin por tal razon solo se mostrara el primer elemento.